# How I can store values in Array

Tags: php, arrays, date

Here is the sample in which the code is working but I wan something different.

```
/** @var array */
    private  $LoadYear = [
       '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022'
    ];
```

What I want is I want to store dates Dynamically Which means the dates should be two past year date and current year and one up coming year.

I was trying like this. But this is not working

```
$Years =date(Y);
/** @var array */
    private  $validYears = [
       $Years-3, $Years-2, $Years-1, $Years, $Years+1, 
    ];
```

Comment: It's because `date(Y)` throws error. Turn error reporting. It should be `(int)date('Y')`

Comment: An example would be very helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Through debugging the existing code, it should not be too hard to spot the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, optionally, as of PHP 7.4, followed by a type declaration, followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value**.

**emphasis by me*

---

This means, you need to initialize the property from somewhere else. For example the constructor of the class in question. E.g.:

```
class Example
{
    private array $validYears;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $Years = date('Y');

        $this->validYears = [
            $Years - 3, $Years - 2, $Years - 1, $Years, $Years + 1,
        ];
    }
}
```